# how to capture the props value inside the event attribute function when use the map function on it

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, jsx

I am very new to React and JS. So inside this jsx, I have this `this.props.searchresult` array, and every element is an object. So I use the `map` function to create a `li` element for every object, and also inside the `li` there is a `select` tag, which has multiple `option` tags. I want to use the event attribute function `onChange()` for select.

But the problem is, how can I pass this `book` value to the event trigger function?

```
{this.props.searchresult.map((book) => (
  <li key={book.id}>
    <div className="book">
      <div className="book-top">
        <div 
          className="book-cover" 
          style={{ 
            width: 128, 
            height: 193, 
            backgroundImage: `url(${book.imageLinks.thumbnail})`
          }}
        />
        <div className="book-shelf-changer">
          ***<select onChange={this.updateBookStatus}>***
            <option value="move" disabled>Move to...</option>
            <option value="currentlyReading">Currently Reading</option>
            <option value="wantToRead">Want to Read</option>
            <option value="read">Read</option>
            <option value="none">None</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div className="book-title">{book.title}</div>
    <div className="book-authors">{book.authors}</div>
  </div>
 </li>         
))}
```

By the way, my event trigger function is

```
updateBookStatus = (event) => {
  const val = event.target.value;

  // const bookObj = {
  //   id: book.id,
  //   imageURL: book.imageLinks.thumbnail,
  //   title: book.title,
  //   authors: book.authors
  // };
  // this.props.moveToReading(bookObj);

  console.log(`The value is ${val}`);
  // console.log(`The current book is ${book}`)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
updateBookStatus = (event, book) => {
    // your code here
}
```

and on your component

```
<select onChange={event => this.updateBookStatus(event, book)}>
```

I just create a function that accepts 2 arguments, and send the value of event and book as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

For passing the book value and evens to **updateBookStatus** function use the ES6 property arrow function, Please refer the code below

```
  <select onChange={(event) => this.updateBookStatus(event, book)}>
            <option value="move" disabled>Move to...</option>
            <option value="currentlyReading">Currently Reading</option>
            <option value="wantToRead">Want to Read</option>
            <option value="read">Read</option>
            <option value="none">None</option>
          </select>
```

Here **{(event) => this.updateBookStatus(event, book)}** updateBookStatus has two arguments one is one event and another one is book value .
The event arguments can be used to get the selected **item event.target.value**